# Non-symmetric positive definite matrices properties

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request, positive-definite

I need some references about non-symmetric positive definite matrices properties. Also if exists, references about determining the range of values for Off-Diagonal elements to guarantee a certain matrix is positive definite.

Comment: What kind of properties would you be interested in exactly? Determinant? Eigenvalues? Factorization?

Comment: What's your definition of "positive definite" without assuming self-adjointness?

Comment: @David I´d like to focuse on eigenvalues, but if there are more properties also would be interesting to know.

Comment: @JochenGlueck positive definiteness means having all eigenvalues greater than zero. In the literature, always the authors focuses on tests for knowing if symmetic matrices are also positive definite, but never on non-symmetric. That is what I need.

Comment: @JoséPatiño: Thanks for your response! Well, but without symmetry you don't even know that all eigenvalues are real... So you want criteria for the eigenvalues to be both real and positive?

Comment: @JochenGlueck a matrix A is positive definite if for every non-zero vector $v$,$ v^{t}Av > 0$, positive eigenvalues is just a consequence from that

Comment: @David: Well, my point is that I'm not sure what the OP is actually asking about. According to his previous comment, he's interested in positive eigenvalues (but I agree that this shouldn't be called 'positive definite'). I also don't think there's a generally acepted standard definition of positive definiteness in the non-selfadjoint case (since many authors prefer not to define the notion at all in this case).

Comment: @David: By the way, the condition $v^tAv > 0$ for all real $v$ does actually *not* imply that all eigenvalues of $A$ are positive; there can still be non-real eigenvalues.

Comment: @JochenGlueck It does imply, however, that the real parts of the eigenvalues are positive

Comment: @BenGrossmann: Yes. More generally, the property is (for a real matrix $A$) equivalent to the numerical range of $A$ being contained in the open right halfplane. But I'm not sure whether it's beneficial to list various related properties here as long as OP hasn't really clarified what he is after. ;-)

Comment: Yes, I'm after properties for real matrices.